# SharePoint Designer 2010: “Unable to load workflow actions from the server. Please contact you server administratior.”

Tags: workflow

Our farm was created with multiple web apps and site collections, prior to my arrival.  In one specific web app, I can create workflows with not problem at all in the all the site collections that have been created under the /sites/ level from the root portal, but I get the error shown in the title when I try to create a workflow at the top level.

For example:

//gi/sits/site1 - workflow can be created and all is well

//gi - if I try to create a workflow here, or at a subsite created here, I receive the following error:
“Unable to load workflow actions from the server.  Please contact you server administrator.”

At top level sites for other web apps, such as //demo, I am able to create workflows with no problem at all.  Google searching has turned up nothing that seems definitive, although I am continuing to search.  So far our .actions file is not the issue, and using Fiddler does not give me an error that tells me of a missing file.

Any hints or ideas, especially a solution, greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you using https? can you try using the default zone aam? Such as `http://servername/sites/sitecollection/subsite`

Comment: Not using https, just plain old http.  Maddening part is all the site collections created in the web app work just fine, except for the one that is not under "sites".  So the full url is like:

Comment: Not using https, just plain old http.  Maddening part is all the site collections created in the web app work just fine, except for the one that is not under "sites".  I spoke with the person who set up these site collections, and he does not remember doing anything different in the setup process.

Comment: Did you try navigating with the default aam? Also, have you tried the root site and navigating to the subsites from within SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Yes, tried getting to this every way I can think of.  I can navigate to any of the sites with no trouble at all, it is just a problem when I try to do anything with a Workflow.  The only thing that I have seen as a solution, a problem with the .actions or a missing file, don't seem to be the case, as the files that would be missing would affect the entire web app, not just the root site.

Comment: can you try logging in with the farm administrator account?

Comment: Tried that one as well.  Even tried with the Service Account, and the account used when the farm was created.  What is strange is that this was, I believe, the very first webapp created on the farm.  Every webapp created since does not have this problem.  All site collections, including the root site, in the other webapps work just fine.

Comment: `Central Administration > SharePoint Designer Settings` `Site Collection Administration > SharePoint Designer Settings` make sure SharePoint Designer is enabled in these menu options.

Comment: Just check again, all SharePoint Designer options are set for all the web applications.  Also checked the inividual Site Collections, they are turned on there as well, same as on ones that work.  I am still puzzled as to why this only affects the top level of one web app?  Any thoughts?